# Simplify these expressions

Tags: trigonometry

$$\frac{1}{(1+\tan^2x)}+\frac{1}{(1+\cot^2x)}$$
It resultet to me that it is $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$ Am I right?
The other is:
$$\frac{\tan x}{(1-\tan^2x)}\times \frac{(\cot^2x-1)}{\cot x}$$. It result to me that t is $\sin^2x$, but it is not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, more generally, for $a\ne-1$,
$$
\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{1}{1+a^{-1}}=\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{a}}
=\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{a}{a+1}=1
$$
For the second one, consider, for $a\ne-1$, $a\ne0$ and $a\ne1$,
$$
\frac{a}{1-a^2}\frac{a^{-2}-1}{a^{-1}}=
\frac{a}{1-a^2}\frac{\dfrac{1}{a^2}-1}{\dfrac{1}{a}}=
\frac{a}{1-a^2}\frac{1-a^2}{a^2}\,a=1
$$

Answer (score 1):

we have $$1+\tan(x)^2=\frac{\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2}{\cos(x)^2}=\frac{1}{\cos(x)^2}$$
$$1+\cot(x)^2=\frac{1}{\sin(x)^2}$$
for the second one we have
$$\frac{\cot(x)^2-1}{\cot(x)}=\frac{1-\tan(x)^2}{\tan(x)}$$

Answer (score 1):

let $y=\tan x$ so that $\cot x=1/y$.

The first becomes:
$$
\frac{1}{1+y^2}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{y^2}}=\frac{1+y^2}{1+y^2}=1
$$

and the second:

$$
\frac{y}{1-y^2}\frac{\frac{1}{y^2}-1}{\frac{1}{y}}=\frac{y}{1-y^2}\frac{1-y^2}{y}=1
$$

Answer (score 0):

First one is correct as $1+\tan^2x=\sec^2x$ and $1+\cot^2x= cosec^2x$

For the second one just put $\cot x = \frac{1}{\tan x}$. You wil get $1$.